# Team Foundation Server: Azure DevOps Office Integration 2019

Tags: excel, tfs

I use for our project "Azure DevOps Office Integration 2019" to connect Excel 2016 with our TFS v15.

Everything works fine. The query result are showed in an Excel-Sheet.

My question has a security background:
It is possible to disable the "Publish" functionality, from the TFS Site, so that the reports of the work-items are read-only from Excel?

Thx in advance

Comment: Work item permissions are set at the area path level. If you have a user who does not have the ability to edit work items, they will not be able to publish changes. Refer to the documentation.

Comment: Thx for the keyword.

Comment: Your suggestion is to regulate the single user with his permissions.
I want to know,If there is additionally a way to generate a workflow to modify the work-items only form the web-interface and Excel should used only for export, independently of the user permissions.

Comment: Hi @KevinLu-MSFT, until now there is no progress. It seems, that the only way to manage the permission of the publish functionality form Excel, are the user permissions of the TFS.

Comment: @AndreStony Yes, you are right. Currently managing user permissions on TFS is the only way. If you would like that feature, please visit the [suggestion portal](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) and create a request for this feature.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to setting the user edit work item permissions, I am afraid we cannot disable the publish function in TFS or Excel.

Here is [a suggestion ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1188267/in-teams-add-in-for-excel-hide-or-disable-the-publ.html) in the suggestion portal. You can track and vote this suggestion ticket. Voting helps increase the priority of the issue by consolidating customer impact under one feedback.